# CSS: hover-issues specifically on iOS 5.1

Tags: css, safari, hover

I'm currently working on a cross-browser Dropdown-Menu.
But currently I have some issues specifically on iOS 5.1 while "hovering" (means: Touching) the Main-Level Navigation links.

On iOS >= 6.0 the link action is prevented using return false and the submenu changes visibility to show and opacity to 1.

But on iOS 5.1 nothing happens. Neither the link-action nor the dropdownmenu shows.

EDIT: Code-Sample

```
$(function() {
    if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
        $("#mainNavigation ul li.dropactive > a").click(function() {
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

Any special workarounds for this iOS Safari?

Cheers,
~MxAgent

Comment: You should avoid hover events for touch based devices, however it sounds like your issue is more javascript related, perhaps show some code so people can be more helpful?

Comment: I added a code example.. :)

Comment: Generally speaking, `:hover` is intended for events related to mouse cursors, which many phones (save perhaps BlackBerrys) don't have. No iOS device has a cursor to interact with `:hover` pseudo-classes.

Comment: For iOS Devices the `:hover`-Event is called upon touch.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to "hover", add a "focus" selector.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp